# Add "vendor product code" to a QWEB report in odoo 13

Tags: odoo-13, qweb

In the built-in sales order report, if a product has "vendor product code" set, it will show that number in front of the product's name. If it is not set, it will show the "internal reference".

We have created a new report and would like to show the internal reference/vendor product code in a column of its own.

I am unable to figure out how to reference a specific vendor for a specific product and obtain the "vendor product code". I.E. I don't know what field from what model to use.

In pseudo-code (not qweb but you get the idea):

```
if(sales_order_line.vendor_product_code.is_set())

    print( sales_order_line.vendor_product_code)

else

    print( sales_order_line.product.internal_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `custom` new `report` on the table which contain the `order-line` , So you can take the idea from here which test in default odoo `sale order` **Quotation report**.

> Test-Product: On the purchase tab, `seller_ids` have vendor set with vendor_code & default_code(internal reference) too.

**Code Example,**

```
<t t-foreach="doc.order_line" t-as="line">
    <t t-set="code" t-value="line.product_id.seller_ids[0].product_code if line and line.product_id and line.product_id.seller_ids and line.product_id.seller_ids[0].product_code else line.product_id.default_code"/>
    <td name="td_name"><span t-field="line.name"/><br/>Code: <span t-esc="code"/></td>
</t>
```

From the above **code**, it is just for a way to use in the `report` `q-web`, as I have used here to get the **1st seller** from the **multiple lists**.

so do your changes as per your customization

**Improved logic for Custom Requirement in Code**:

```
<t t-set="code" t-value="line.product_id.seller_ids.filtered(
                    lambda x: doc.partner_id == x.name).product_code if line and line.product_id and line.product_id.seller_ids else line.product_id.default_code"/>
```

like this way you can check that your **current partner** is having the **seller list**.
But you can add a more precise condition so for multi-partner find in seller you can not have an error with some unique condition added as per your customization.

Comment: This is great. I have a follo0w up question; `line.product.seller_ids[0]` will give me the 1st seller, not necessarily the seller of the PO. Can I use `o.partner_id` to look up the product code? Something like `line.product_id.seller_ids[line.product_id.seller_ids.index(line.partner_id)].product_code`? I know `.index()` doesn't work in QWEB (I tried), so the only other option i see is a `t-foreach` and a `t-if` to loop through all the `seller_ids` until I find one that matches `o.partner_id` and store that in a varible.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart not you can not work with any .index() method, you can use it but in pythonic way which you have to trigger .py function from XML. but here I add the logic so you can work along with the same.

Comment: @Matthew Goulart If this solution work you then for the future community fellow make this solution acceptable with that anyone can take the reference as acceptable here.